# Url rewriting with "-" symbol for dividing parameters

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config

My current url is: mysite.com/datasheet/100-DE-xmas2016-6

in web.config:

```
<rule name="myrule">
   <match url="^datasheet/([_0-9a-z-]+)-([_0-9a-z-]+)-([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="ajax/datasheet.aspx?shop={R:1}&amp;language={R:2}&amp;product={R:3}" />
</rule>
```

it **will not rewrites** to

mysite.com/ajax/datasheet.aspx?shop_id=100&language=DE&product=xmas2016-6

Why???
How to make possible product "xmas2016-6" to work?
The list "mysite.com/datasheet/100-DE-xmas20166" will work. But I really want to use product as "xmas2016-6" (in regular expression set to [_0-9a-z-], but its like ignoring my "-" symbol in product parameter or what?)

Answer (score 0):

This rule will work for you:

```
<rule name="myrule">
    <match url="^datasheet/([_0-9a-z]+)\-([_0-9A-Z]+)\-([_a-z]+[0-9]{4})([0-9]{1})$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/ajax/datasheet.aspx?shop={R:1}&amp;language={R:2}&amp;product={R:3}-{R:4}" />
</rule>
```

Regexp `^datasheet/([_0-9a-z]+)\-([_0-9A-Z]+)\-([_a-z]+[0-9]{4})([0-9]{1})$` is splitting `datasheet/100-DE-xmas20166` into four groups:

- {R:0}   `datasheet/100-DE-xmas20166`
- {R:1}   `100`
- {R:2}   `DE`
- {R:3}   `xmas2016`
- {R:4}   `6`